# Trouble running Magento on Linux

Tags: frontend, setup, docker, frontend-error

My friend was trying to run a source code for a store on Magento. His setting up for magento includes PHP 7.4, Docker and Composer.
However, this was what he got:
[image]

I'm new to Magento so I too have no idea what's happened and I'm still looking for a solution to it. Can anyone guide me on how to fix it?
Here is the git link to his source code: https://github.com/pqthinh/magento/tree/magento

Thank you for reading!

Comment: just regenerate your static assets by running the command `bin/magento s:s:d --theme=Hiddentechies\bizkick --area=frontend --force` and clean your cache `bin/magento c:c`